# build in Android resource compilation failed

Tags: android-studio

i can not run my application in  Android studio There id the Picture where you can see more about the problem[there is what android studio studio shows me when i try to run the app click there to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsZFM.png)

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that there is a compilation error in your XML file: a spelling mistake, an extra character, an incorrect namespace...
It would be helpful if you poste your XML code from activity_main.xml so that we can see what the problem is

Comment: thanks Nina for ur time the problem is resolved i've juste forget one bracks

Comment: That's great! If iy really was a spelling mistake, an extra character, an incorrect namespace and my answer answered you question, would you mind accepting it? You just simply mark the tick button! Thanks!